# In C++, what is the difference between an expression and a literal?

Tags: c++

My book defines an expression as "a programming statement that has a value" and a literal as "a piece of data that is written directly into a program's source code", but I'm still having some trouble distinguishing between the two. For example, is 3+3 a literal AND an expression, or just an expression? Why?

```
int number = 2+2;
```

Is this whole statement an expression, or just the right value? Why? This whole statement has a value of 4, so surely the whole statement is an expression?

In my mind, an expression usually involves operators and a literal involves a single piece of data like 4, "Hello", 'A', etc. I also understand that a literal can be an expression because of unary operators such as - or +. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Literals

Comment: No. A statement **is not** an expression. Noticeably, there is a segregation between lvalues and rvalues in C++, as illuminated by the use of rvalue references as introduced in C++11.

Comment: The definitions are both incorrect in the case of C++. Tell us the book so we can avoid it.

Comment: @EJP it's tough to define "expression"

Comment: @EJP The book is called "Starting out with C++ From Control Structures through Objects" by Tony Gaddis (8th Edition). It is the required textbook for my programming class at college. I've only gotten through 4 chapters so far, but it seems to be really well written, so I wouldn't be so quick to write it off over two definitions. Then again, I'm a complete beginner and you might have a lot more experience then me.

Comment: An expression that can be completely evaluated at compile time is converted to a "literal" value by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies a computation. An expression can result in a value and can cause side effects.

A literal is one of the following:

- integer literal
- character literal
- floating point literal
- string literal
- boolean literal
- pointer literal

I won't try to give the formal definition of each of these, but each is basically just a value.

There's one more type of literal that's somewhat special though:

- user-defined literal

Although user-defined literals are literals, the value of the literal is defined in terms of the result of evaluating an expression.

References:

Expressions: [expr]
Literals: [lex.literal]

(For those unfamiliar with it, the tag in square brackets is the notation used to specify sections in the C++ standard).

Answer (score 0):

A literal is something like the number 7 for example. When converted to assembly code, the literal 7 remains quite visible in the code:

```
MOV   R1,  7  ; move the number 7 as a value into register R1
```

An expression is something that needs to be evaluated. Generally, you'll find something along the lines of `C=A+B;` where `A+B` is an expression.

> An expression is a sequence of operators and their operands, that
>   specifies a computation. Expression evaluation may produce a result
>   (e.g., evaluation of 2+2 produces the result 4) and may generate
>   side-effects (e.g. evaluation of std::printf("%d",4) prints the
>   character '4' on the standard output).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Literals

Comment: I feel like this answer could be much more helpful if you'd take the time to edit and update it.